# What is the difference between types.AssertableTo, types.AssignableTo and types.ConvertibleTo?

Tags: go

`func AssertableTo(V *Interface, T Type) bool` is [explained](https://golang.org/pkg/go/types/#AssertableTo) this way:

> AssertableTo reports whether a value of type V can be asserted to have type T.

`func AssignableTo(V, T Type) bool` is [documented](https://golang.org/pkg/go/types/#AssignableTo) as:

> AssignableTo reports whether a value of type V is assignable to a variable of type T.

Finally, there's also `func ConvertibleTo(V, T Type) bool` ([doc](https://golang.org/pkg/go/types/#ConvertibleTo)):

> ConvertibleTo reports whether a value of type V is convertible to a value of type T.

From the description they seem like doing the same thing and so I'm not clear which one to chose if I need to check if a variable has a specific type in runtime. In which situations will I not get the expected result?

Comment: [Assignability](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignability), [Conversions](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions), [Type assertions](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions)

Comment: @Peter Is the only difference that these are described under different URLs or what prevented you to elaborate this to a real answer?

Answer (score 1):

The language specification describes the concepts behind the functions listed in the question: [Assignability](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignability), [Conversions](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions), [Type Assertion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions).

None of these functions tell you if the type of a value is equal to some other type.  Further, none of those methods are applicable at runtime.

Compare `reflect.Type` values to determine if two types are the same at runtime.

Here's an example.  The following line of code gets the `reflect.Type` for an arbitrary type `T`:

```
t := reflect.TypeOf((*T)(nil)).Elem()
```

To determine if a `reflect.Value` has type `T`, simply compare types:

```
var x T
v := reflect.ValueOf(x)
fmt.Println(v.Type() == t) // prints true for all concrete types T.
```